# Binary Tree: Why does the recursion stop when you do root.left or root.right but not root?

Tags: recursion, binary-tree

This question is based off of inverting a binary tree in [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/invert-binary-tree).
Why does the recursion stop when you do `root.left` or `root.right` but not `root`?

My original solution was `return self.invertTree(root)`, but obviously I had to think of a base case to stop the recursion, but could not think of one. I was surprised to see that the solution (below) just had the recursion go through the left and right children and it would automatically stop.

```
def invertTree(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: TreeNode
        """
        # Base Case
        if root is None:
            return root

        # 1 iteration.
        placeholder = root.left
        root.left = root.right
        root.right = placeholder
        
        # This part doesnt make sense.
        # Why does it stop if you do root.left or root.right but not root?
        self.invertTree(root.left)
        self.invertTree(root.right)
        return root
        # return self.invertTree(root)
```

Comment: In order for the recursion to stop, the recursive value needs to converge to a base case. If you call `self.invertTree(root)` then the recursive value will not change, i.e. it won't converge to a base case. That is, when you call `self.invertTree(root)`, it will recursively call `self.invertTree(root)`, which will again recursively call `self.invertTree(root)`, which will again call `self.invertTree(root)`, and so on ad infinitum. So, on each successive recursive call you need to ensure that your recursive value is becoming smaller and smaller. Only then will the recursion stop.

Comment: Thus, for the recursion to stop you must call the recursive function on `root.left` and `root.right`. For example, when you call `self.invertTree(root)` it will recursively call `self.invertTree(root.left)` and `self.invertTree(root.right)`, which will recursively call `self.invertTree(root.left.left)`, `self.invertTree(root.left.right)`, `self.invertTree(root.right.left)`, and `self.invertTree(root.right.right)`, and so on until it processes the whole tree. As you can see on each recursive step, the recursive value becomes smaller and smaller until we reach the base case.